# Invalid Json in Body on Rest Api

Tags: node.js, angular, rest, api

I am building a CRUD App with Angular using a Rest Api and Mongo DB.
In my App I send a Post Object to the Rest Api, but the Request has a Invalid Json in the body:

```
{
 '{"_id":"","user":"Maius_XX","content":"asdasfd","lits":13,"shits":2,"comments":{},"timestamp":"Sun Jan 27 2019 21:07:11 GMT 0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)"}': ''
}
```

I tried to parse the body or send other information, but there is still invalid Json.

My Angular Code:

```
createNewPosts(post: Post) {
    const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
    })
};

this._http.post<Post>(this.urlPosts, post, httpOptions)
    .subscribe(
        res => {
            console.log(res);
        },
        err => {
            console.log("Error occured " + err );
        }
    );
```

My Backend:

```
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {    

const product = new Product({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    user: req.body.user,
    content: req.body.content,
    lits: req.body.lits,
    shits: req.body.shits,
    comments: req.body.comments,
    timestamp: req.body.timestamp
});
console.log(req.body);
product.save().then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        res.status(201).json({
            message: "Handling Post",
            createdProduct: result
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        });
    });
});
```

and:

```
app.use(morgan('dev')); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Alllow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET');
        return res.status(200).json({});
    }
    next();
});

app.use('/products', productRoutes);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const error = new Error('Not found');
    error.status = 404;
    next(error);
})

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(error.status || 500);
    res.json({
        error: {
            message: error.message
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the **Content-Type** from:

```
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
```

To:

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
```

Comment: @MaG. Cors has nothing to do with your front-end. You need to configure it on the back-end. Can you share the error?

Comment: yes cors needs to be configured in the backend, but with application/x-www-form-urlencoded it works... 
thats the error: 
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/products/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: @MaG. If you want to send data using application/x-www-form-urlencoded you will need to serialize the data.      If you want to send it using json try allowing any origin, any headers and any method, while developing this shouldn’t be an issue, try to match all these setting latter when in production